# Match substring from a list to multiple columns in another file

Tags: perl, unix, text-processing

I am fairly new to linux and to perl programming. I have exhausted all search options with no answer.
I have a master file "master.txt" that contains all the interactions known with 2 columns in which the items on same row are known to interact. I have a list of items "list.txt" that I want to be the search criteria to return results from the master file if it is contained in Column 1 as well as Column 2. All files are tab delimited. For eg: 
If this is the master file: "master.txt"

```
AppleP001   BallP002
AppleP002   CatP001 
BallP001    DogP001
BallP002    AppleP001
CatP001 AppleP002
DogP001 BallP001
DogP002 ZebraP001
ElephantP001    CardinalP001
FishP001    AntelopeP001
```

And this search file: "list.txt"

```
Apple
Ball
Cat
Dog
```

The resulting file should only contain Apple* ,Ball*, Cat* and Dog* on both columns but remove duplicate items:

I tried using grep:

```
grep -f list.txt master.txt > Sub_list.txt
```

But I get this:

```
AppleP001       BallP002
AppleP002       CatP001
BallP001        DogP001
BallP002        AppleP001
CatP001 AppleP002
DogP001 BallP001
DogP002 ZebraP001
```

How do I remove duplicates (consider it a duplicate if both items are in the same row, does not matter what column they are in) and remove unrelated data from the output file and get this?

```
AppleP001   BallP002
AppleP002   CatP001 
BallP001    DogP001
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please note that questions here are expected to be about details of _your code_ (and why it's failing).  Look over [Help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), they are short and informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little heavy if the files are very large but that problem isn't  mentioned

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Path::Tiny;
use List::Util qw(uniq any all);

my ($file, $flist) = ('master.txt', 'list.txt'); 

my @search = path($flist)->lines({ chomp => 1 });

# Sort words within each line so then filter out duplicate lines
my @filtered = uniq map { join ' ', sort split } path($file)->lines;

# Each word on the line needs to match a word in @search list
my @result = grep { all { found($_, \@search) } split } @filtered;

say for @result;

sub found { return any { $_[0] =~ /^$_/ } @{$_[1]} }
```

The output agrees with my understanding of the problem description

```
AppleP001 BallP002
AppleP002 CatP001
BallP001 DogP001
```

If you can't have [Path::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Path-Tiny-0.104/lib/Path/Tiny.pm) that provides `path` for some reason, open files and check that, and instead of `path(...)->lines` read filehandles (so in list context) and do `chomp @search;`

---

The last part, written out a bit

```
# Each word on the line needs to match a word in @search list
my @result = grep { 
    my ($w1, $w2) = split; 
    any { $w1 =~ /^$_/ } @search  and  any { $w2 =~ /^$_/ } @search;
} @filtered;
```

Comment: Thank you zdim! The comments are very helpful and helped me learn your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR { a[$1]; next }    # read list and hash to a
{                          # process master
    b=""                   # reset buffer
    for(i in a)            # iterate thru a
        if(index($0,i)) {  # if list item is found in current master record
            b=$0           # set the record to buffer
            delete a[i]    # remove list entry from a
        }
        if(b) print b      # print b
}' list master             # mind the order
AppleP001   BallP002
AppleP002   CatP001 
BallP001    DogP001
```